# Unity Android build не появляется canvas

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Столкнулся с проблемой после Android build на unity 2D. Когда запускаю игру все отображается нормально, но на телефоне пропал весь UI. Img1-как на телефоне, Img2- как должно быть. В чем может быть проблема?! введите сюда описание изображения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема либо в коде, либо в префабе, либо в сцене (не сохранены изменения, не та сцена)

Comment: Покажите хотя бы код появления интерфейса и скрин структуры сцены/префаба, где размещается UI

Comment: В самой unity игра отлично работает

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/VZvaz9zGwq4HCA Ссылка на изображение Иерархии

Comment: Объекты должны появляться сразу

Comment: Можете показать скрин списка сцен с Build Settings?

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/HIfG5JSb9TEG5A Всего 2 сцены, первая сцена работает нормально, все кнопки взаимодействуют. Во второй сцене canvas вообще не отображается

Comment: Код надо вставлять прямо в пост, текстом

Comment: Скрин инспектора канваса в студию.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переместить объекты на канвасе по оси z. Может звучать странной для 2d игры, но это можно сделать.

Для этого нажмите на специальную кнопку в левой верхнем углу окна сцены. Дальше выделите объекты внутри канваса и перемещайте их, или с помощью обычного инструмента перемещения, или с помощью инспектора.

Второй вариант возможно и без перехода в 3d пространство, но рекомендую перейти что бы ничего не напутать с координатами.